# How to generate dynamic UITableView according to a XML?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to create a menu bar in my iPad app according to a XML file. I decided to use dynamic UITableView to implement it.

The XML file is something like this:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
     <menuBar>
          <menu id="1" text="File">
               <menuItem id="11" text="New Panel" />
               <menuItem id="12" text="Open" />
          </menu>
          <menu id="2" text="Edit">
               <menuItem id="21" text="Size" />
               <menuItem id="22" text="Font" />
               <menu id="3" text="Option">
                    <menuItem id="31" text="XX" />
               </menu>
          </menu>
     </menuBar>
```

So there may be several levels of the menu bar. A menu may contain another menu as well as some menuitems, for example, `menu id="2"` has a `menu id="3"`, and `menu id="3"` has its own `menuItem`.

I know how to create `UITableViewCell` dynamically. The problem is I don't know how to create next level when the cell is a kind of `menu` and how to create cells in this deeper level `UITableView`.

If you know how to implement this, please help me. Or if there is a better way to generate a menu instead of using `UITableView`, please let me know. Cheers :)

==========UPDATE===========

I just receive XML once, so may I create these tableview when I'm parsing the XML? and I do not need to create them again later.

For example, when there is a `menu` element, I add a `cell` to current level's `tableview`, and create a `new tableview` as next level, now when there is a `menuItem` element, I add a new cell to this `new tableview`. When there is no more elements in the current menu element, return to upper level tableview.

Comment: You want us to do your parsing job?:( that sounds a bit lazy

Comment: @TotumusMaximus nonono, I know how to parse XML, what I want to know is how to add a cell that can push to a new tableview and add cells to this newly created tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your table view delegate (usually a subclass of `UITableViewController`), implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to react to the user tapping a cell. The implementation then needs to 1) create a new instance of another `UITableViewController` that will manage the next level of your menu hierarchy; and 2) push the new controller onto the navigation stack of a `UINavigationController`.

A very rough draft of how this might look like:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

  YourTableViewController* aController = [[YourTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:aController animated:YES];
  [aController release];
}
```

This code sample assumes that the controller you are writing the code for already is on the stack of a navigation controller (`self.navigationController`).

In any case, you should have a good look at Apple's documentation for the class `UINavigationController`, and at their "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS".

Comment: I just receive XML once, so may I create these tableview when I'm parsing the XML? and I do not need to create them again later. For example, when there is a `menu` element, I add a cell to current level's tableview, and create a new tableview as next level, now when there is a `menuItem` element, I add a new cell to this new tableview. When there is no more elements in the current `menu` element, return to upper level tableview.

Comment: I've tried your code. `NextTableViewController* aController = [[NextTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    aController.items = [[self.menus objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] menuitems];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:aController animated:YES];` but when I press the cells in the first tableview, there is nothing in the next tableview. I've checked that `[[self.menus objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] menuitems]` is not empty. Anything I missed here?

Comment: Finally it works... Thanks a lot. I will use the same tableviewcontroller for every level in the menu.

Comment: @Manted Glad it works now. As a final suggestion, you may want to study the Model-View-Controller (MVC) design pattern (unless you already know it, of course). In your case you could have a model class that parses the XML and stores the resulting `menus` array. You only create a single instance of this class, the resulting model object can then be shared by all the table view controllers. In this design you separate the concern of XML parsing from the concern of presenting the data. Good luck with your app.

Comment: yeah i parse the xml and store the result in a class, I just want to use tableview to present these data. but i parse the xml in my main viewcontroller, maybe i have to improve this design. :)